# Clearing Eclipse console after launching a debug session

Tags: java, eclipse, console

Is there a way to clear the console output from a previous debug session in Eclipse?

Every time I stop my server and launch again, it is needed to perform a "clear console" right click to clear off the outputs so the current logs are not mixed up with the previous ones.

I'm wondering if there is an automated way of doing this by some configuration in Eclipse, not programatically.

After some researches in questions unfortunately did not find any result to adress this.

Eclipse version: 2022-03 (4.23.0)
Build id: 20220310-1457

Tried:

- Finding Eclipse configurations for clearing console output after starting a ApacheTomcat server.

It is expected:

- Having Console tab cleared right after a debug session is initiated.

Comment: Steps to reproduce? Take a look a `Common` tab on tomcat launch config.

Comment: I would focus on the tomcat settings, this is not the behavior for all debug sessions